# Whether LettuceConnectionFactory have version restrictions on redis and springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

The project need a custom *RedisConnectionFactory* and finds a problem:
when using *LettuceConnectionFactory*, the runtime always reports java.lang.NullPointerException, while *JedisConnectionFactory* can pass tests.
I think that whether *LettuceConnectionFactory* have version restrictions on redis and springboot?

Developing environment:

Springboot: 2.1.0.release

redis:3.2.8

jdk8.

**Java Code**

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactoryTest(){
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 6379));
    }

    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactoryTest(){
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 6379));
    }

}
```

**Test Code**

```
@Autowired
private RedisConfig redisConfig;

@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

@Test
public void test(){

    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConfig.lettuceConnectionFactoryTest());
    ValueOperations<String, String> valueOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    valueOperations.set("test", "test123");
    System.out.println(valueOperations.get("test"));

}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1085)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1065)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:865)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:340)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:132)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:211)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:236)
at com.test.infrastructure.InfrastructureApplicationTests.test(InfrastructureApplicationTests.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is occurring because `LettuceConnectionFactory` has not been initialised. It should be initialised by Spring Framework calling `afterPropertiesSet()` which is one of the standard bean lifecycle methods. That method isn't being called as your `LettuceConnectionFactory` isn't a bean due to a missing `@Bean` annotation on `RedisConfig.lettuceConnectionFactoryTest()`.

Adding `@Bean` on `RedisConfig.lettuceConnectionFactoryTest()` should solve your problem. It will also allow you to inject `LettuceConnectionFactory` directly (into an `@Autowired` field in your test) rather than injecting `RedisConfig` and then calling `lettuceConnectionFactoryTest()` on it.

Comment: I've run into this problem, what I don't understand is that `JedisConnectionFactory` does not have this issue. I've just tested jedis and modify the code to adjust lettuce and now it's broken event when `lettuceConnectionFactory` is passed to `RedisTemplate` which called `afterPropertiesSet()`