# Confusion about the spring beans with the same type and different parameter as the parameter of another function

Tags: java, spring-boot

To customize `LettuceConnectionFactory`, I have created the two functions, which have same return type and different parameters, one is single node config, other is  cluster config. The code as follows:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean(name = "singleFactory")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory createSingleFactory(RedisSingleConfig redisSingleConfig){...}

    @Bean(name = "clusterFactory")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory createClusterFactory(RedisClusterConfig redisClusterConfig){...}

}
```

when they are called, the return value(LettuceConnectionFactory) is a parameter of another function. The code as follows:

```
@Autowired
private RedisActivityClusterConfig testConfig;

@Autowired
private RedisItemConfig redisItemConfig;

@Autowired
private RedisConfig redisConfig;

@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

@Test
public void test(){
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConfig.createClusterFactory(testConfig));
    ValueOperations<String, String> valueOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    System.out.println(valueOperations.get("test"));
}
```

But in the way, spring will report `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: singleFactory,clusterFactory`

---

Question added:

Since the project is slightly more complicated, there are many redis single servers A, B, C... and cluster servers A, B, C..., and they have different ip, port and pool strategies. My original idea is that dynamically generate different LettuceConnectionFactories by injecting into different redisConfig as parameters such as RedisConfig_A, RedisConfig_B, RedisConfig_C (configs can be obtained by the redis.properties in Resources), then use these LettuceConnectionFactories to create customized RedisTemplates. My confusion is that whether these objs: RedisConfig, LettuceConnectionFactories can be autowired? I have tried many ways, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own custom `RedisTemplate` otherwise the default one will try to autowire a default `RedisConnectionFactory`, thus your error.

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean(name = "redisTemplateA")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplateA(RedisClusterConfig redisClusterConfigA) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(createClusterFactoryA(redisClusterConfigA));
        return template;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "singleFactoryA")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory createSingleFactoryA(RedisSingleConfig redisSingleConfigA){...}

    @Bean(name = "clusterFactoryA")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory createClusterFactoryA(RedisClusterConfig redisClusterConfigA){...}

    // other combinations as needed
}
```

Then use this `RedisTemplate` in your tests. More details/examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial)

**Extra** you cannot have dynamic config passing since as your previous question stated, you have to have `LettuceConnectionFactory` as beans, not with basic initialization. Therefore you would need to define all combinations of `LettuceConnectionFactories` for each config, e.g. `singleFactoryA` (using `configA`), `clusterFactoryB` (using `configB`), then just create multiple `RedisTemplate`'s with whichever combination of config+factory you need. Always using different bean names, this should work.

If you would need all combinations, you can then store all these `RedisTemplate`'s into some `Table`, where keys would be config type (`A`, `B`, `C`) and factory type (`single`, `cluster`) with values as templates themselves. `Table<ConfigType, FactoryType, RedisTemplate> redisTemplateTable`, where I just assumed `ConfigType` & `FactoryType` as your custom enum classes

Comment: The exception is the same of my another question.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128219/whether-lettuceconnectionfactory-have-version-restrictions-on-redis-and-springbo/53129524#53129524]

Comment: I have tried the way you mentioned aboved, sorry about it does not work. I gave a more detailed supplement to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Autowired` annotation tells `Spring` where the Injection Point is (i.e. where an injection needs to occur). On finding such injection point, `Spring` tries to find a configured bean (configured via  `@Bean`) of the same type, if it finds such bean, it injects it to the injection point.

If it finds two or more such beans, it will throw the exception. To avoid the exception, we have to use the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: one question, let's suppose there is ClassA, and it has two child classes: ClassB and ClassC. these child classes are beans while ClassA is not a bean. let's also suppose that some function expects ClassA object as an argument. Is the error going to occur in this scenario?

Comment: in other words, is it possible to autowire and pass ClassB or ClassC object to that function instead of ClassA object

Comment: Yes, this works how you describe. But for plain Autowired definition Spring expects exactly one. i.e. You must have only ClassB instance, or ClassC instance. If you have both, then Autowired must have name attribute specified.